# How to get context in custom pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I wish to create a pipe that can read my current context and put it into my string template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myApp',
  template: `
    <input [ngModel]="template">
    <div *ngFor="let a of ['x','y']">
      <div *ngFor="let b of [1,2]">
        <p>output: {{ template | replace:this }}<p> // replace is my custom pipe
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
class TextComponent {
  attr1= 'Attr1';
  attr2= 'Attr2';
  template: string;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'replace', pure: false
})
export class ReplacecPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(template: string, component: any) {
    // perform replace process
  }
}
```

So if I put '{{attr1}} then {{a}} then {{b}}' into template, I expect the following result:

```
output: Attr1 then x then 1
output: Attr1 then x then 2
output: Attr1 then y then 1
output: Attr1 then y then 1
```

Is there any syntax or keyword for me to pass it in just like 'this'. Maybe $context? or $scope in angularjs?

Please ignore how I perform the replacement process, I just want to know how can I get the view context without needing me to pass in a and b one by one like 'replace:this:a:b' due to it might be too many to map.

Prefered it can work as simple as 'replace:this:$context', in $context i can get a, b and other contexts.

2 hours after I post this question, I learn about $implicit but still no idea how to use it in pipe.

Comment: you could do something like `{{template | replace:attr1:attr2}}` and your pipe would be something like `transform(template: string, attr1: any, attr2: any)`

Comment: @HarryNinh thanks for your answer, I forgot to include the requirement which assumes that I can't pass in a and b (map one by one) due is too much for me to map in every single context

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass in context (here only for `attr1`):

```
<input [ngModel]="template">
<div *ngFor="let a of ['x','y']">
  <div *ngFor="let b of [1,2]">
    <p>output: {{ template | myReplace:attr1:a:b }}<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the replace pipe:

```
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {    
    transform(template: string, attr: string, a: string, b:number) {
        let res = template
                    .replace("{{attr}}", attr)
                    .replace("{{a}}", a)
                    .replace("{{b}}", b.toString());
        return res;
    }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khsfit) full working example that prints:

```
output: Attr1 then x then 1
output: Attr1 then x then 2
output: Attr1 then y then 1
output: Attr1 then y then 1
```